# Replace javascript Paypal button .render() calls with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, paypal, e-commerce

I can make a javascript based paypal buy button usign this code (not shown the API key `src` variable)

```
paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I'd like to render these buttons using React.

```
  render() {
    return (

      <button className="empty-cart-button" onClick={this.handleEmptyCart}>Empty Cart</button>
      <div className="paypal-buttons-container">
        <div id="paypal-button"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

How can I render these correctly in the React Render function?

Answer (score 0):

The official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) ([storybook)](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) can be used from react.

What should be replaced are any and all references to `actions.order.create` and `actions.order.capture`. Though it hasn't made its way to react documentation yet, these functions have been deprecated and should not be used for any new integration. Instead, replace them with calls to two backend routes that create and capture an order, respectively.

---

Examples of such a backend can be found in the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) or [this TypeScript sample app](https://github.com/paypal-examples/paypal-sdk-server-side-integration). Neither of those use React in their frontend, but their backend routes do use the v2/checkout/orders API to create and capture the order with PayPal and that is what is important about them as a reference example.